# Trouble with coding a logical test in VBA

Tags: vba, logic

I'm creating an improved schedule for my workplace, trying to implement macros to error check data that is input manually.

I've got one code that works as expected, but when I've changed the logical test, it ceases to work.

I'm not skilled in VBA coding myself, so I'm looking for some assistance.

```
Sub ErrorMsg2()
  Dim a As Long, b As Long
  Dim Msg As String

  For a = 28 To 44 Step 4
       For b = 4 To 8
        If Application.CountIf(Range("C" & a).Resize(, 6), "(=0.7 or =0.8)") Then
              If Cells(a, b) = (0.7 Or 0.8) And Cells(a, (b - 1)) = (0.9 Or 1) Then
                 If Msg = "" Then Msg = Cells(24, b) Else Msg = Msg & ", " & Cells(24, b)
              End If
           End If
           Next b
           MsgBox Range("A" & a) & " Has been scheduled a night shift followed by a day shift on " & Msg & vbNewLine & "Please Rectify." & vbNewLine & _
          "Press OK to acknowledge.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Error"
       Msg = ""
  Next a
End Sub
```

For example if cell D28 = 0.8 and cell C28 = 1, the message box should appear.

However the message box is appearing when b = 9.

Answer (score 1):

The “Or” clause works differently, here the relevant snippet:

```
If Application.CountIf(Range("C" & a).Resize(, 6), 0.7) + Application.CountIf(Range("C" & a).Resize(, 6), 0.8) > 0 Then
    If (Cells(a, b) = 0.7 Or Cells(a, b) = 0.8)  And (Cells(a, (b - 1)) = 0.9 Or Cells(a, (b - 1)) = 1) Then
        If Msg = "" Then
            Msg = Cells(24, b)
        Else
            Msg = Msg & ", " & Cells(24, b)
        End If
    End If
Next b
```